# Scrapy executing different spiders in different times with reactor

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to click a button on django website and my spider supposed to start scraping. I try CrawlerProcess but because of I am using different spiders. I decided to use CrawlerRunner. After first Crawling everything is fine but second process giving me this error.

```
twisted.internet.error.ReactorNotRestartable
```

I try this topic's solution:
[ReactorNotRestartable error in while loop with scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39946632/reactornotrestartable-error-in-while-loop-with-scrapy)

So I try solution as following code but the crawler never stop and it says `ReactorAlreadyRunning`

```
def test():
    configure_logging({'LOG_FORMAT': '%(levelname)s: %(message)s'})
    runner = CrawlerRunner(get_project_settings())
    d = runner.crawl(myspider.My_Spider)
    d.addBoth(lambda _: reactor.stop(stop_after_crawl=False))
    reactor.run()
```

It is not letting me crawl another spider. So how can I run crawl multiple spiders on different times on my website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This topic helps me to solve the problem. I just need to install **crochet** and add **setup()** on top of my code.

[Solution link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50140887/django-celery-scrappy-error-twisted-internet-error-reactornotrestartable)