# scrapy-spash: SplashRequest response object differs between invocation by scrapy crawl vs CrawlerProcess

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler, scrapy-splash

I'd like to use scrapy-splash to fetch both the html and screenshot png of the target page. I need to be able to invoke it programmatically. According to the [spashy doc](https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#render-json), specifying

```
endpoint='render.json'
```

and passing argument

```
'png': 1
```

should result in a response object ('scrapy_splash.response.SplashJsonResponse') with a .data attribute that contains decoded JSON data representing a png screenshot of the target page.

When the spider (here named 'search') is invoked with

```
scrapy crawl search
```

The result is as expected, with response.data['png'] containing the png data.

However, if it is invoked via scrapy's CrawlerProcess, a different response object is returned: 'scrapy.http.response.html.HtmlResponse'. This object does **not** have the .data attribute.

Here's the code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest
import base64

RUN_CRAWLERPROCESS = False

if RUN_CRAWLERPROCESS:
    from crochet import setup
    setup()

class SpiderSearch(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'search'
    user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36'

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = ['https://www.google.com/search?q=test', ]
        splash_args = {
            'html': 1,
            'png': 1,
            'width': 1920,
            'wait': 0.5,
            'render_all': 1,
        }
        for url in urls:
            yield SplashRequest(url=url, callback=self.parse, endpoint='render.json', args=splash_args, )

    def parse(self, response):
        print(type(response))
        for result in response.xpath('//div[@class="r"]'): 
            url = str(result.xpath('./a/@href').extract_first())
            yield {
                'url': url
            }

        png_bytes = base64.b64decode(response.data['png'])
        with open('google_results.png', 'wb') as f:
            f.write(png_bytes)

        splash_args = {
            'html': 1,
            'png': 1,
            'width': 1920,
            'wait': 2,
            'render_all': 1,
            'html5_media': 1,
        }
        # cue the subsequent url to be fetched (self.parse_result omitted here for brevity)
        yield SplashRequest(url=url, callback=self.parse_result, endpoint='render.json', args=splash_args)

if RUN_CRAWLERPROCESS:
    runner = CrawlerProcess({'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36'})
    #d = runner.crawl(SpiderSearch)
    #d.addBoth(lambda _: reactor.stop())
    #reactor.run()
    runner.crawl(SpiderSearch)
    runner.start()
```

Restating:

```
RUN_CRAWLERPROCESS = False
```

and invoking by

```
scrapy crawl search
```

response is type

```
class 'scrapy_splash.response.SplashJsonResponse'
```

But setting

```
RUN_CRAWLERPROCESS = True
```

and running the script with CrawlerProcess results in response of type

```
class 'scrapy.http.response.html.HtmlResponse'
```

(p.s. I had some trouble with ReactorNotRestartable, so adopted crochet as decribed in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44788051/reactornotrestartable-twisted-and-scrapy), which seems to have fixed the problem. I confess I don't understand why, but assume it is unrelated...)

Any thoughts on how to debug this?

Answer (score 1):

If you're running this code as a standalone script the settings module will never be loaded and your crawler will not know about the Splashy middleware (which is what's adding the `.data` attribute you're referencing in `.parse`).

You can load these settings within your script by calling `get_project_settings` and passing the result to your Crawler:

```
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings

# ...

project_settings = get_project_settings()


process = CrawlerProcess(project_settings)
```