# Scrapy CrawlerRunner: Output missing

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I have been using the method described on stackoverflow (https://stackoverflow.com/a/43661172/5037146) , to make scrapy run from script using Crawler Runner to allow to restart the process.

However, I don't get any console logs when running the process through CrawlerRunner, whereas when I using CrawlerProcess, it outputs the status and progress.

Code is available online: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/14hKTjvWWrP--h_yRqUrtxy6aa4jG18nJ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `CrawlerRunner` you need to manually setup logging, which you can do with `configure_logging()`. See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#run-scrapy-from-a-script

Comment: Thanks man, it works ! I also found out that using CrawlerProcess instead or CrawlerRunner automatically yields logs.

Comment: I found that you need to configure both `LOG_FILE` inside configure_logging and settings, in order for the `CrawlerRunner` to log properly.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `CrawlerRunner` you have to manually configure a logger
You can do it using `scrapy.utils.log.configure_logging` function

for example

```py
import scrapy.crawler
from my_spider import MySpider

runner = scrapy.crawler.CrawlerRunner()
scrapy.utils.log.configure_logging(
            {
                "LOG_FORMAT": "%(levelname)s: %(message)s",
            },
        )
crawler = runner.create_crawler(MySpider)
crawler.crawl()
```