# Web-Scraping: moving to next pages using Scrapy for getting all data

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I would need to scrape all the reviews from a product on Amazon:

[https://www.amazon.com/Cascade-ActionPacs-Dishwasher-Detergent-Packaging/dp/B01NGTV4J5/ref=pd_rhf_cr_s_trq_bnd_0_6/130-6831149-4603948?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=B01NGTV4J5&pd_rd_r=b6f87690-19d7-4dba-85c0-b8f54076705a&pd_rd_w=AgonG&pd_rd_wg=GG9yY&pf_rd_p=4e0a494a-50c5-45f5-846a-abfb3d21ab34&pf_rd_r=QAD0984X543RFMNNPNF2&psc=1&refRID=QAD0984X543RFMNNPNF2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01NGTV4J5)

I am using Scrapy to do this. However it seems that the following code is not scraping all the reviews, as they are split n different pages. A human should click on all reviews first, the click on next page. I am wondering how I could do this using scrapy or a different tool in python.
There are 5893 reviews for this product and I cannot get this information manually.

Currently my code is the following:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class My_Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'spid'
    start_urls = ['https://www.amazon.com/Cascade-ActionPacs-Dishwasher-Detergent-Packaging/dp/B01NGTV4J5/ref=pd_rhf_cr_s_trq_bnd_0_6/130-6831149-4603948?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=B01NGTV4J5&pd_rd_r=b6f87690-19d7-4dba-85c0-b8f54076705a&pd_rd_w=AgonG&pd_rd_wg=GG9yY&pf_rd_p=4e0a494a-50c5-45f5-846a-abfb3d21ab34&pf_rd_r=QAD0984X543RFMNNPNF2&psc=1&refRID=QAD0984X543RFMNNPNF2']

    def parse(self, response):
        for row in response.css('div.review'):
            item = {}

            item['author'] = row.css('span.a-profile-name::text').extract_first()

            rating = row.css('i.review-rating > span::text').extract_first().strip().split(' ')[0]
            item['rating'] = int(float(rating.strip().replace(',', '.')))

            item['title'] = row.css('span.review-title > span::text').extract_first()
            yield item
```

And to execute the crawler:

```
process = CrawlerProcess({
})

process.crawl(My_Spider)
process.start()
```

Can you tell me if it is possible to move to next pages and scrape all the reviews?
This should be the page where are stored the reviews.

Answer (score 0):

With the url  `https://www.amazon.com/Cascade-ActionPacs-Dishwasher-Detergent-Packaging/product-reviews/B01NGTV4J5/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_paging_btm_next_2?ie=UTF8&reviewerType=all_reviews&pageNumber=<PUT PAGE NUMBER HERE>` you could do something like this:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class My_Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'spid'
    start_urls = ['https://www.amazon.com/Cascade-ActionPacs-Dishwasher-Detergent-Packaging/product-reviews/B01NGTV4J5/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_paging_btm_next_2?ie=UTF8&reviewerType=all_reviews&pageNumber=1']

    def parse(self, response)
         for row in response.css('div.review'):
             item = {}
             item['author'] = row.css('span.a-profile-name::text').extract_first()
             rating = row.css('i.review-rating > span::text').extract_first().strip().split(' ')[0]
             item['rating'] = int(float(rating.strip().replace(',', '.')))
             item['title'] = row.css('span.review-title > span::text').extract_first()
             yield item
         next_page = response.css('ul.a-pagination > li.a-last > a::attr(href)').get()
         yield scrapy.Request(url=next_page))
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I am getting this error: `ReactorNotRestartable: ` with no further information about the error. This is caused by `---> 33 process.start()`, then `--> 293         reactor.run(installSignalHandlers=False)  # blocking call`

Comment: Hm, did you replace the item = ReviewItem() and the ... part with the your item and code?

Comment: I replaced the `item = ReviewItem()` and the `...` part  with:            ` item = {}

            item['author'] = row.css('span.a-profile-name::text').extract_first()

            rating = row.css('i.review-rating > span::text').extract_first().strip().split(' ')[0]
            item['rating'] = int(float(rating.strip().replace(',', '.')))

            item['title'] = row.css('span.review-title > span::text').extract_first()`

Comment: The problem is here: `process = CrawlerProcess({
})

process.crawl(My_Spider)
process.start()`. when I try to execute the process and store data

Comment: Have a look at this and see if any of that solves it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41495052/scrapy-reactor-not-restartable
Also, you can try to change back the code, Does it work then?

Comment: I have tried with the solution proposed there. But I am stil getting the same error, here ----> 6 run_spider(My_Spider)