# PyQt5 executable GUI freezing when running scrapy CrawlerRunner

Tags: python, scrapy, pyqt5, pyinstaller

When I transform my script in a standalone executable using Pyinstaller and try to run a CrawlerRunner process that I got from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43661172/13825145) (which is connected to the Update Database button) my GUI opens a new window and completely freezes. When running in script form it works just fine. Like this:

[image]

**In main.py:**

```
class MyGUI(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        ...
        self.update_db_button.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked_update)
        ...

    def on_clicked_update(self):
        """Gives command to run scraper and fetch data from the website"""
        run_spider()
        gui_warnings.update_notification()
```

**In scrapy_run.py**

```
from multiprocessing import Queue
from multiprocessing import Process
from twisted.internet import reactor
from scrapy import crawler
from currency_scraper.currency_scraper.spiders.investor import InvestorSpider


# from https://stackoverflow.com/a/43661172/13825145
def f(q):
    try:
        runner = crawler.CrawlerRunner(
            {
                "USER_AGENT": "currency_scraper",
                "SCRAPY_SETTINGS_MODULE": "currency_scraper.currency_scraper.settings",
                "ITEM_PIPELINES": {
                    "currency_scraper.currency_scraper.pipelines.Sqlite3Pipeline": 300
                    }
            }
        )
        deferred = runner.crawl(InvestorSpider)
        deferred.addBoth(lambda _: reactor.stop())
        reactor.run()
        q.put(None)
    except Exception as e:
        q.put(e)

def run_spider():
    q = Queue()
    p = Process(target=f, args=(q,))
    p.start()
    result = q.get()
    p.join()
    if result is not None:
        raise result
```

**Console log**

```
[9004] PyInstaller Bootloader 3.x
[9004] LOADER: executable is C:\Users\Familia\Documents\ProgramaþÒo\Python\Projetos\Currency_converter\dist\Currency Converter.exe
[9004] LOADER: homepath is C:\Users\Familia\Documents\ProgramaþÒo\Python\Projetos\Currency_converter\dist
[9004] LOADER: _MEIPASS2 is NULL
[9004] LOADER: archivename is C:\Users\Familia\Documents\ProgramaþÒo\Python\Projetos\Currency_converter\dist\Currency Converter.exe
[9004] LOADER: Extracting binaries
[9004] LOADER: Executing self as child
[9004] LOADER: set _MEIPASS2 to C:\Users\Familia\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI90042
[9004] LOADER: Setting up to run child
[9004] LOADER: Creating child process
[9004] LOADER: Waiting for child process to finish...
[240] PyInstaller Bootloader 3.x
[240] LOADER: executable is C:\Users\Familia\Documents\ProgramaþÒo\Python\Projetos\Currency_converter\dist\Currency Converter.exe
[240] LOADER: homepath is C:\Users\Familia\Documents\ProgramaþÒo\Python\Projetos\Currency_converter\dist
[240] LOADER: _MEIPASS2 is C:\Users\Familia\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI90042
[240] LOADER: archivename is C:\Users\Familia\Documents\ProgramaþÒo\Python\Projetos\Currency_converter\dist\Currency Converter.exe
[240] LOADER: SetDllDirectory(C:\Users\Familia\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI90042)
[240] LOADER: Already in the child - running user's code.
[240] LOADER: manifestpath: C:\Users\Familia\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI90042\Currency Converter.exe.manifest
[240] LOADER: Activation context created
[240] LOADER: Activation context activated
[240] LOADER: Python library: C:\Users\Familia\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI90042\python38.dll
[240] LOADER: Loaded functions from Python library.
[240] LOADER: Manipulating environment (sys.path, sys.prefix)
[240] LOADER: sys.prefix is C:\Users\Familia\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI90042
[240] LOADER: Pre-init sys.path is C:\Users\Familia\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI90042\base_library.zip;C:\Users\Familia\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI90042
[240] LOADER: Setting runtime options
[240] LOADER: Bootloader option: pyi-windows-manifest-filename Currency Converter.exe.manifest
[240] LOADER: Initializing python
[240] LOADER: Overriding Python's sys.path
[240] LOADER: Post-init sys.path is C:\Users\Familia\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI90042\base_library.zip;C:\Users\Familia\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI90042
[240] LOADER: Setting sys.argv
[240] LOADER: setting sys._MEIPASS
[240] LOADER: importing modules from CArchive
[240] LOADER: extracted struct
[240] LOADER: callfunction returned...
[240] LOADER: extracted pyimod01_os_path
[240] LOADER: callfunction returned...
[240] LOADER: extracted pyimod02_archive
[240] LOADER: callfunction returned...
[240] LOADER: extracted pyimod03_importers
[240] LOADER: callfunction returned...
[240] LOADER: Installing PYZ archive with Python modules.
[240] LOADER: PYZ archive: PYZ-00.pyz
[240] LOADER: Running pyiboot01_bootstrap.py
[240] LOADER: Running pyi_rth__tkinter.py
[240] LOADER: Running pyi_rth_multiprocessing.py
[240] LOADER: Running pyi_rth_pkgres.py
[240] LOADER: Running pyi_rth_mplconfig.py
[240] LOADER: Running pyi_rth_mpldata.py
[240] LOADER: Running pyi_rth_twisted.py
[240] LOADER: Running pyi_rth_pyqt5.py
[240] LOADER: Running main.py
c:\users\familia\documents\programação\python\projetos\currency_converter\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py:493: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning:
The MATPLOTLIBDATA environment variable was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.1 and will be removed in 3.3.
exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
[14188] PyInstaller Bootloader 3.x
[14188] LOADER: executable is C:\Users\Familia\Documents\ProgramaþÒo\Python\Projetos\Currency_converter\dist\Currency Converter.exe
[14188] LOADER: homepath is C:\Users\Familia\Documents\ProgramaþÒo\Python\Projetos\Currency_converter\dist
[14188] LOADER: _MEIPASS2 is C:\Users\Familia\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI90042
[14188] LOADER: archivename is C:\Users\Familia\Documents\ProgramaþÒo\Python\Projetos\Currency_converter\dist\Currency Converter.exe
[14188] LOADER: SetDllDirectory(C:\Users\Familia\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI90042)
[14188] LOADER: Already in the child - running user's code.
[14188] LOADER: manifestpath: C:\Users\Familia\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI90042\Currency Converter.exe.manifest
[14188] LOADER: Activation context created
[14188] LOADER: Activation context activated
[14188] LOADER: Python library: C:\Users\Familia\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI90042\python38.dll
[14188] LOADER: Loaded functions from Python library.
[14188] LOADER: Manipulating environment (sys.path, sys.prefix)
[14188] LOADER: sys.prefix is C:\Users\Familia\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI90042
[14188] LOADER: Pre-init sys.path is C:\Users\Familia\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI90042\base_library.zip;C:\Users\Familia\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI90042
[14188] LOADER: Setting runtime options
[14188] LOADER: Bootloader option: pyi-windows-manifest-filename Currency Converter.exe.manifest
[14188] LOADER: Initializing python
[14188] LOADER: Overriding Python's sys.path
[14188] LOADER: Post-init sys.path is C:\Users\Familia\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI90042\base_library.zip;C:\Users\Familia\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI90042
[14188] LOADER: Setting sys.argv
[14188] LOADER: setting sys._MEIPASS
[14188] LOADER: importing modules from CArchive
[14188] LOADER: extracted struct
[14188] LOADER: callfunction returned...
[14188] LOADER: extracted pyimod01_os_path
[14188] LOADER: callfunction returned...
[14188] LOADER: extracted pyimod02_archive
[14188] LOADER: callfunction returned...
[14188] LOADER: extracted pyimod03_importers
[14188] LOADER: callfunction returned...
[14188] LOADER: Installing PYZ archive with Python modules.
[14188] LOADER: PYZ archive: PYZ-00.pyz
[14188] LOADER: Running pyiboot01_bootstrap.py
[14188] LOADER: Running pyi_rth__tkinter.py
[14188] LOADER: Running pyi_rth_multiprocessing.py
[14188] LOADER: Running pyi_rth_pkgres.py
[14188] LOADER: Running pyi_rth_mplconfig.py
[14188] LOADER: Running pyi_rth_mpldata.py
[14188] LOADER: Running pyi_rth_twisted.py
[14188] LOADER: Running pyi_rth_pyqt5.py
[14188] LOADER: Running main.py
c:\users\familia\documents\programação\python\projetos\currency_converter\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py:493: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning:
The MATPLOTLIBDATA environment variable was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.1 and will be removed in 3.3.
  exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
```

Comment: The `q.get()` method locks the eventloop until the process finishes, and the lock freezes the GUI. Instead you should use qt5reactor or qreactor that allows to run the crawler and Qt in the same eventloop as my answer to the duplicate question shows.

Comment: I couldn`t make the reactor restartable (every time I click the button Update Database I want to be able to run Scrapy) using qt5reactor, could you please show me an example?