# Scrapy - rotating arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy, python-multiprocessing

I'm struggling with rotating arguments with Scrapy. My goal is to scrape 100+ diverse pages, so I create a uniwersal template in Scrapy for that (similar info web portals):

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from w3lib.html import remove_tags

class UniwersalscraperSpider(CrawlSpider):

    name = 'UniwersalScraper'
    allowed_domains = [domain]
    start_urls = [url]

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=xpath_all_articles_links_on_page), 
        callback='parse', follow=True),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=xpath_pagination)),
        )

     def parse(self, response):
            Ugly_text = response.xpath({xpath_text}).extract()
            Good_text = [remove_tags(text) for text in Ugly_text]
            yield {
                "Title" : response.xpath(xpath_title).get(),
                "Date" : response.xpath(xpath_date).get(),
                "Summarize":response.xpath(xpath_summarize).get(),
                "Text" : Good_text,
                "Url" : response.url       
            }
```

Script is visiting web portal, extract data from all articles links on web page. After that is visiting next page and repeat.

In order to rotate XPaths I prepared a sample list in Excel file:

https://docdro.id/TOA9mBA

After researching on Stackoverflow I found out this problem with multiprocessing solution:

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41495052/scrapy-reactor-not-restartable)

I'm running code below on Linux to avoid python problems with windows:

```
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor 
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings 
from w3lib.html import remove_tags
import pandas as pd
from urllib.parse import urlparse
import numpy as np
import scrapy.crawler as crawler
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
from twisted.internet import reactor

class UniwersalscraperSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'Uniwersalscraper'

    def __init__(self,url="",domain="", xpath_text="",xpath_title = "",xpath_date ="",xpath_pagination="" ,xpath_summarize="", xpath_all_articles_links_on_page="", *args, **kwargs):
        super(UniwersalscraperSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)  
        self.start_urls = [url]
        self.allowed_domains = [domain]
        self.xpath_text= xpath_text
        self.xpath_title = xpath_title
        self.xpath_date = xpath_date
        self.xpath_summarize= xpath_summarize
        self.xpath_pagination = xpath_pagination
        self.xpath_all_articles_links_on_page = xpath_all_articles_links_on_page
        
        
        self.rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=xpath_all_articles_links_on_page), callback='parse', follow=True),
                      Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=xpath_pagination)),
                )

    def parse(self, response):         
        Ugly_text = response.xpath(self.xpath_text).getall()
        Good_text = [remove_tags(text) for text in Ugly_text]
        yield {
            "Title" : response.xpath(self.xpath_title).get(),
            "Date" : response.xpath(self.xpath_date).get(),
            "Summarize" : response.xpath(self.xpath_summarize).get(),
            "Text" : Good_text,
            "Url" : response.url       
        }


def run_spider(spider, Strings_and_XPaths):
    def f(q):
        try:
             runner = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())

             deferred = runner.crawl(spider,
                                url = Strings_and_XPaths[1],
                                domain = Strings_and_XPaths[2],
                                xpath_title = Strings_and_XPaths[5],
                                xpath_date = Strings_and_XPaths[6],
                                xpath_summarize = Strings_and_XPaths[7],
                                xpath_text = Strings_and_XPaths[8],
                                xpath_all_articles_links_on_page= Strings_and_XPaths[3],
                                xpath_pagination = Strings_and_XPaths[4]
         )
             deferred.addBoth(lambda _: reactor.stop())
             reactor.run()
             q.put(None)

             runner = crawler.CrawlerRunner()
             deferred = runner.crawl(spider)
             deferred.addBoth(lambda _: reactor.stop())
             reactor.run()
             q.put(None)
        except Exception as e:
             q.put(e)

    q = Queue()
    p = Process(target=f, args=(q,))
    p.start()
    result = q.get()
    p.join()

    if result is not None:
        raise result

#/mnt/c/Users/Admin/Desktop/Repository/Scrapers/Web_scraping.xlsx  # linux
#'C:\\Users\Admin\Desktop\Repository\Scrapers\Web_scraping.xlsx'   # windows

df = pd.read_excel(('/mnt/c/Users/Admin/Desktop/Repository/Scrapers/Web_scraping.xlsx') , sheet_name='GotoweXPath')
domains = [urlparse(domain).netloc for domain in np.array(df['url'])]
df['domain'] = domains   #creating domain based on url

Data = [tuple(r) for r in df.to_numpy()]

#running code
for Strings_and_XPaths in Data:
    run_spider('Uniwersalscraper', Strings_and_XPaths)
```

Here my logs from terminal :

https://docdro.id/C524TB1

It seems like code is able to rotate arguemnts but rules and callback is not working. Crawler is visiting web page and closing. I have no idea why.

*Of course when you paste all of arguments from random row\line excel file, into uniwersal template, crawler spider is working perfectly fine.

Thank you in advance for all sugestions and help.

Comment: Don't use `parse` with CrawlSpider, name the function something else so you won't overwrite the `parse` function.

Comment: I tried to renamed it ("parse_response","extract_response", "parse_response","parse_item","scrape"). Nothing changed. I also on the end of log got:

raise ValueError(f'Missing scheme in request url: {self._url}')
ValueError: Missing scheme in request url:

it seems like my crawler is doing one extra loop and raise this error

Comment: I said it generally, unfortunately I'm having some unexpected errors when trying to run your code on my machine...

Comment: @SuperUser If it helps there is my "working" code on github to clone:

https://github.com/slaw999999999/Scrapy

Comment: Still having the same errors...Sorry.