# Why am I getting "ReactorNotRestartable" error using Scrapy?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm using `Scrapy`  in `Google Colab` but I always get `ReactorNotRestartable` error:

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUEAL.png)

First I installed Scrapy using pip and then I used this code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
  name="test"
 

  def start_requests(self):
    yield scrapy.Request("A valid URL")

  def parse(self, response):
    products=response.css("div.product-card")
    for item in products:
      yield {
          
          "price":products.css("div.price-range::text").get(),
      }

process=CrawlerProcess(settings={
      
    "FEED_URI" : "test.csv",
    "FEED_FORMAT" : "csv"
})

process.crawl(TestSpider)
process.start()
```

I was following a tutorial about "How to use Scrapy in python script" but my code is not working.

Why am I getting "ReactorNotRestartable" error using Scrapy?

Comment: what scrapy version are you using? and how are you running your script ?

Comment: version : 2.7.1 I run that code on a cell in Google Colab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are facing this problem because you are using colab/jupyter notebook because you cannot restart the twisted reactor. you can solve this by either:

- restarting your notebook. You have to restart each time you run the spider.
- Or run your spider locally using python (not jupyter).
- Or you can use crochet. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41495052/scrapy-reactor-not-restartable#answer-47581199) answer for how to set it up.

Answer (score 0):

Use the this example

```py
from twisted.internet import reactor, defer
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner
from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings


class MySpider1(scrapy.Spider):
    # Your first spider definition
    ...


class MySpider2(scrapy.Spider):
    # Your second spider definition
    ...


settings = get_project_settings()
configure_logging(settings)
runner = CrawlerRunner(settings)


@defer.inlineCallbacks
def crawl():
    yield runner.crawl(MySpider1)
    yield runner.crawl(MySpider2)
    reactor.stop()


crawl()
reactor.run()  # the script will block here until the last crawl call is finished`
```