# How restart Scrapy spider

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

What I need:

1. start crawler
2. crawler job done
3. wait 1 minute
4. start crawler again

I try this:

```
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
from time import sleep

while True:
    process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())
    process.crawl('spider_name')
    process.start()
    sleep(60)
```

But get error:

> twisted.internet.error.ReactorNotRestartable

please help me do it right

*Python 3.6

Scrapy 1.3.2

Linux*

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/39955395/2572383

Answer (score 6):

In order to avoid ReactorNotRestartable error, you can try to create a *main.py* file from where to call several times to the crawler from shell using `subprocesses`.

This main.py file could be like this:

```
from time import sleep
import subprocess

timeout = 60

while True:
    command = 'scrapy crawl yourSpiderName'
    subprocess.run(command, shell=True)
    sleep(timeout)
```

Answer (score 5):

I think I found the solution:

```
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.internet import task


timeout = 60


def run_spider():
    l.stop()
    runner = CrawlerRunner(get_project_settings())
    d = runner.crawl('spider_name')
    d.addBoth(lambda _: l.start(timeout, False))


l = task.LoopingCall(run_spider)
l.start(timeout)

reactor.run()
```