# twisted.internet.error.ReactorNotRestartable multiples URLs

Tags: python, scrapy

I use python 3
I use scrapy 2.4.1
I made a script to ask you to input some words and it will search about it my code
The first URL work without problems
and after that, it gives an error

```
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
class Amazon_spiders(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "amazon"
    start = time.time( )
    search = []
    starting=[]
    parse_number=0
    custom_settings = {
        'DOWNLOD_DELAY': 1,
        'LOG_LEVEL': 'INFO',}
    #make folder
    try:
        os.mkdir('results folder')
    except FileExistsError:
        pass
    def __init__(self):
        self.outfile = open(f"results folder/ result date.csv", "w",newline="", encoding="utf-8")
        self.writer = csv.writer(self.outfile)
        self.writer.writerow(['Title', 'Price', 'url', 'Img', 'Ratings', 'Stars'])
        print("***" * 20, "opened")
    def start_requests(self):
        number = input('Enter the number of times to search \n')
        for n in range(int(number)):
            word = input("Enter one sentence to be searched  \n ")
            # Amazon_spiders.search.append(word)
            words = word.strip( )
            # replace space with +
            words = words.replace(' ', '+')
            url = f'https://www.amazon.com/s?k={words}&ref=nb_sb_noss'
            print(f'currant page {url}')
            yield Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)
process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())

# 'amazon' is the name of one of the spiders of the project.
process.crawl('amazon')
process.start( )  # the script will block here until the crawling is finished
```

the error is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ahmed/PycharmProjects/web scraping/Amazon/Amazon/spiders/amazon.py", line 109, in <module>
    process.start( )  # the script will block here until the crawling is finished
  File "C:\Users\ahmed\PycharmProjects\web scraping\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 327, in start
    reactor.run(installSignalHandlers=False)  # blocking call
  File "C:\Users\ahmed\PycharmProjects\web scraping\venv\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\base.py", line 1282, in run
    self.startRunning(installSignalHandlers=installSignalHandlers)
  File "C:\Users\ahmed\PycharmProjects\web scraping\venv\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\base.py", line 1262, in startRunning
    ReactorBase.startRunning(self)
  File "C:\Users\ahmed\PycharmProjects\web scraping\venv\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\base.py", line 765, in startRunning
    raise error.ReactorNotRestartable()
twisted.internet.error.ReactorNotRestartable
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Did you see this question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/39946632/11946287

Comment: I didn`t find an answer